# Why sprite doesn't change without coroutine in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, coroutine, gameobject

I've got a game object "position". Under some conditions a child of this game object (a car) is destroyed. Then the next Car object is instantiated as a child of the "position". If the position is selected, I want the sprite of the car to be changed.

But if I just try something like:

```
if(selected)
{
    position.transform.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = newSprite;
}
```

it doesn't work.

So I tried to do it this way:

```
if(selected)
{
     StartCoroutine(Temp());
}

IEnumerator Temp()
{          
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.000000000001f);
     position.transform.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = newSprite;          
}
```

and now it does.

But I realize it's badly done. Can somebody help please?

Comment: yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.000000000001f); I would not use that. If you want to wait for a frame use yield return null; I am not even sure that value you gave can be turned into float.

Comment: Ok, null is fine. But why can't it work without IEnumerator?

Comment: @mike can't really say why it is not working without seeing your code. But 
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame() would be a better choice.

Comment: WaitForEndOfFrame would not be any better here. The problem with GetComponentInChildren is that it returns the first found including the current object. So if the parent object contains a Sprite or another object in the same hierarchy level, maybe that one is modified. You could print out the name of the game object you are affecting.

Comment: The code samples have errors. You didnt put () in the end of GetComponentInChildren call.

Comment: Of course () is there in my code, thx anyway for notice.

Comment: fafase - only the child has the SpriteRenderer. As you see, the second way works fine.

Comment: Sushant - the code is pretty much the same as I put here. There is Destroy, Instantiate, and transform.parent = position.transform before the given code;